# python 2.7 - trying to print a string and the (printed) output of function in the same line

Tags: python-2.7, printing

I have the following function defined:

```
    def displayHand(hand):
       """
        Displays the letters currently in the hand.

        For example:
        >>> displayHand({'a':1, 'x':2, 'l':3, 'e':1})
        Should print out something like:
           a x x l l l e
        The order of the letters is unimportant.

        hand: dictionary (string -> int)
        """
        for letter in hand.keys():
            for j in range(hand[letter]):
                 print letter,              # print all on the same line
        print ''                            # print an empty line
```

Now, I want to print the following:

```
    Current hand: a b c
```

To do this, I try to do:

```
    print "Current hand: ", displayHand({'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1})
```

And I get:

```
    Current hand: a b c
    None
```

I know that None is printed cause I am calling the print function on the displayHand(hand) function, which doesn't return anything.
Is there any way to get rid of that "None" without modifying displayHand(hand)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you trail a `print` with a `,`, the next print will appear on the same line, so you should just call the two things on separate lines, as in:

```
     def printStuff():
        print "Current hand: ",
        displayHand({'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1})
```

Of course you could just adapt this and create a method like:

```
    def printCurrentHand(hand):
        print "Current hand: ",
        displayHand(hand)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use your function in a print statement, it should return a `string` and not print something itself (and return `None`) - as you would do in a `__str__` method of a class. something like:

```
def displayHand(hand):

    ret = ''
    for letter in hand.keys():
        for j in range(hand[letter]):
             ret += '{} '.format(letter)   # print all on the same line
    # ret += '\n'
    return ret
```

or even

```
def displayHand(hand):
     return ''.join(n*'{} '.format(k) for k,n in hand.items() )
```

Comment: The lower one seems like the more "pythonic" solution here and I had thought about posting it too. Yet, the poster had initially asked for a solution without changing his original method. My answer gives him that. Other people coming here, please note that hiros answer here might be preferable for new projects.

Comment: Well, the upper one would solve my issue if I could change displayHand(). The lower one would not, cause it would not print repeated letters. See the docstring in my original post to see an example of how displayHand() should work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this (or I believe the only way to do this) is to use `return` instead of `print` in your `displayhand()` function. Sorry if I didn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your function 'displayHand' does not have to print the output,
it has to return a string.

```
def displayHand(hand):  
    mystring='' 
    for letter in hand.keys():
        for j in range(hand[letter]):
            mystring+= letter   # concatenate all on the same line
    return mystring
```

BUT, you have to check the '.keys' command help as the order of the input (a/b/c) may not be respected